# C# Xamarin - AddTarget to UILongPressGestureRecognizer passing it a Selector implemented in a parent UIViewController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, segue, viewcontroller

I am having difficulties raising an event from a `UICollectionViewCell` to a handler which exists within a parent `UIViewController`. I am trying to detect a LongPress upon a `UICollectionViewCell` and fire a method in the `UIViewController` - placing the view into an "Edit Mode" show/hiding UI elements and reloading etc. To do so my `UIViewController` method must call a data access layer and thus it makes sense the method is placed at this level in the view hierarchy.

I have followed the official documentation and techniques from [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events/) and the great advice from Adam Kemp [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52661/subscribe-to-an-event-in-a-nested-view-from-another-seperately-nested-uiview).

There are so many conflicting methodologies for achieving this in Xamarin.IOS. Alas, at present, none seem to work in my case. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong!

I have a custom class which inherits from `UICollectionViewCell` which contains a `private UILongPressGestureRecognizer _recognizer;` and method named `UpdateCell` as follows:

```
    public virtual void UpdateCell(bool CanEdit)
    {
        // Other properties and logic omitted for brevity (no relevance to question)

        this._recognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer();
        this._recognizer.MinimumPressDuration = 0.5;
        this._recognizer.AddTarget(this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("OnEditModeActivated"));
        this.AddGestureRecognizer(_recognizer);   
    }
```

I want the Long press to fire the following method within my UIViewController:

```
        [Export("OnEditModeActivated")]
        public async void OnEditModeActivated()
        {
            if (recognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
            {
                this._canEdit = true;
                // call Data Access layer using await 
                _source.Dispose(); // dispose of current UICollectionViewSource object
                _source = new UICollectionViewSource(_data, _canEdit);
                UICollectionView.Source = _source;
            } 
        }
```

The line causing issues is

```
`this._recognizer.AddTarget(this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("OnEditModeActivated:"));`
```

The selector should point to the parent `UIViewController` which has a `public void OnEditModeActivated` decorated with `[Export("OnEditModeActivated:")]`.

I can see the compiler running into the "unrecognized selector" exception due to `this` (1st arg passed to `AddTarget`) obviously being the UICollectionViewCell rather than the `UIViewController` and thus it will look to resolve `AddTarget` by UICollectionViewCell (instance) -> OnEditActivated (does not exist).

Instead of `this` I need to reference the parent `UIViewController` but I don't want to pass it by reference to the `UpdateCell` method - this would mean passing the reference through many layers thus my code becoming somewhat spaghetti like.

If anyone can explain a better way, by all means feel free. I looked at raising an event within the `UICollectionViewCell` instance but to no avail. Moreover I can't seem to get the delegation pattern right in Xamarin!

The problem is the hierarchy I am using being: `UIViewController -> UICollectionView -> UICollectionViewSource -> UICollectionViewCell`.

I am sure it is possible to raise an event/call delegate/call method and resolve at the view controller level...

Thanks for taking the time to help on this.

All the best,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiring up the `_recognizer` to the `ContentView` and declaring a method within `this` fixed my issue.

I changed:

```
this.AddGestureRecognizer(_recognizer);
```

to:

```
 cell.ContentView.AddGestureRecognizer(_recognizer);
```

and created a OnLongPressed method at the same level decorated with `Export["OnLongPressed:"] which raises an event resolved at the`UIViewController` level.

As an aside, the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` raises mutliple events and one should check the long press has actually **ended** otherwise any further events / method calls will occur more than once, for example:

```
if(recognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
{
    // Raise events call methods here only when the long press ended
}
```

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`s will fire with multiple states which you can test using the `State` property [documentation here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer.State/).